# How to factorize $x^4+2x^2-x+2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

look at this:
$$x^4+2x^2-x+2$$
How to factorize it?

It should be changed to be in the form of standard factorization formulas.

Comment: I tried a way and I wanted to share it but I realized it had a bid mistake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write

$$x^4+2x^2-x+2=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$$

Then $a+c=0$, $bd=2$, $ad+bc=-1$ and $b+d+ac=2$. If you want integer values for $a,b,c,d$, you must have $b=\pm2$ or $\pm1$, and afters some checks,

$$x^4+2x^2-x+2=(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+2)$$

Here is a more systematic approach. From the preceding equations, you have

$$c=-a$$
$$a(b-d)=1$$
$$b+d=2-ac=2+a^2$$

From $b-d=1/a$ and $b+d=2+a^2$, you get

$$b=\frac12(2+a^2+1/a)$$
$$d=\frac12(2+a^2-1/a)$$

Then, the equation $bd=2$ leads to

$$(2+a^2)^2-1/a^2=8$$

With $t=a^2$,

$$t(2+t)^2-8t-1=0$$

Or

$$t^3+4t^2+4t-8t-1=t^3+4t^2-4t-1=0$$

This one is a reciprocal equation, and it has the obvious solution $t=1$. Then you can choose $a=1$ and $c=-1$, then $b=2$ and $d=1$.

---

As DanielV remarks below, this is a general method to solve the quartic equation

$$x^4+Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D=0$$

First, let $x=z-A/4$, by expanding you can check that the coefficient of $z^3$ vanishes, and you have to solve

$$z^4+Uz^2+Vz+W=0$$

Then, as above, you write

$$z^4+Uz^2+Vz+W=(z^2+az+b)(z^2+cz+d)$$

And after expanding the RHS and equating coefficients with same power of $z$, you get $a+c=0$, $b+d+ac=U$, $ad+bc=V$, $bd=W$.

Then

$$c=-a$$
$$b+d=U+a^2$$
$$b-d=-V/a$$

Hence

$$b=\frac12(U+a^2-V/a)$$
$$d=\frac12(U+a^2+V/a)$$

Thus

$$4bd=4W=(U+a^2)^2-V^2/a^2$$

And with $t=a^2$, you have to solve

$$t(U+t)^2-4Wt-V^2=0$$

$$t^3+2Ut^2+(U^2-4W)t-V^2=0$$

This is a cubic equation, so you have proved that to solve a quartic, you just have to solve first a cubic, which is supposed to be easier (and there are indeed methods to solve the cubic).
Then, there remains two trinomials to solve, and you are done.

This method is also described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_by_factoring_into_quadratics), along with others. Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) for solutions of the cubic equation.

Comment: An observation that Rene Decartes (1596-1650) exploited in his solution to the quartic is that that $x^4 + qx^2 + rx + s = (x^2 + kx + l)(x^2 - kx + m)$, in other words, when the $x^3$ term has been removed then you can assume $a = -c$.

Comment: @DanielV Actually, this *is* Descartes' method, in a particular case. You get a cubic, and from a solution of the cubic you solve the quartic. Here, thankfully, the cubic is easy.

Comment: Indeed, it  might be worth mentioning to the questioner that if he knows how to remove the $x^3$ term by substitution, then this is a very general approach.

Comment: could you explain how you knew that $x^4+2x^2-x+2$ can be written in the shape of $(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$?

Comment: @BlueSky Every real polynomial (of arbitrary degree $n\geq 1$) is a product of real polynomials of degree at most $2$. It's a particular case of the [fundamental theorem of algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), which states that every nonconstant complex polynomial is a product of complex polynomials of degree 1. You simply take the complex conjugates pairs of roots, for example $z$, $\bar z$ yield the factor $x^2-(z+\bar z)x+z \bar z$, which is real.

Comment: @BlueSky Of course, you don't know in advance that the method will actually yield a cubic and hence allow you to solve the quartic. But in the end you know it works.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=x^4+2x^2-x+1=(x^4-x^3+x^2)+(x^3 -x^2+x)+(2x^2-2x+2)$$

$$f(x)=x^2(x^2-x+1)+x(x^2-x+1)+2(x^2-x+2)=(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+2)$$

Answer (score 0):

The zeroes of this quartic are $$\frac12\pm i\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$$ and $$-\frac12\pm i\frac{\sqrt 7}{2}$$ Since there are no real zeroes, it can't be factored down to linear factors with only real coefficients.

However, this does mean that the complete factorization is
$$\left(x-\tfrac12- i\tfrac{\sqrt 3}{2}\right)\left(x-\tfrac12+ i\tfrac{\sqrt 3}{2}\right)\left(x+\tfrac12- i\tfrac{\sqrt 7}{2}\right)\left(x+\tfrac12+ i\tfrac{\sqrt 7}{2}\right)
$$

**Addendum:** Following the suggestion of @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, this can be partially combined to produce two quadratics with all real coefficients:
$$\left(x-\tfrac12- i\tfrac{\sqrt 3}{2}\right)\left(x-\tfrac12+ i\tfrac{\sqrt 3}{2}\right) = x^2 - x + 1$$ and $$\left(x+\tfrac12- i\tfrac{\sqrt 7}{2}\right)\left(x+\tfrac12+ i\tfrac{\sqrt 7}{2}\right) = x^2 + x + 2$$ which gives a factorization into $$(x^2 - x + 1)(x^2 + x + 2)$$ with the quadratics not factorizable with real coefficients.

Comment: This is wrong. A real polynomial can always, at least theoretically (in practice there may be no closed form, but it's another matter), be factored with real factors of degree 1 or 2. And here it's even relatively easy.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: I meant linear factors, sorry. Will add this correction, thanks.

Comment: Ah, ok then. But I think the OP is looking for $any$ factorization (not necessarily with linear factors). Anyway, if you know the pairs of complex conjugate roots, you can find easily the factors of degree 2, but I fear it's done the other way around usually : to solve the quartic, one method involves factoring in two trinomials.